# eGalax TouchScreen doesn't react

Tags: raspbian-jessie, touchscreen

Years ago I bought a screen on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Touch-Screen-Monitor-Raspberry-Driver/dp/B00GZCUNQ8/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t)

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax
>   TouchScreen

A couple days I'm trying to get it running on my PI (newest Jessie on Pi B Rev2).
I stumbled over a bunch of how-tos and tried a lot of stuff (except compiling a new kernel) but I was not able to get the touch running.

I tried to [replace the kernel](http://danielscheidler.de/projekte/arduino-haussteuerung/touchscreen-am-raspberry-pi-einrichten/) - didn't even boot (prob. wrong version?).
I flashed the delivered [ISO](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/sain-amzn/20/20-011-208/7lcd.gz) - booted, but no touch reactions.
Was not able to setup the [drivers](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/sain-amzn/20/20-011-208/eGalaxTouch+driver.zip).
And after reading [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/718) I decided to do nothing than just run the `xinput_calibrator`. No reaction either.

So after some research at SE I found [how to](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2013/01/17/how-to-get-evtouch-touch-screen-kit-working-in-linux/) that gave me some commands to figure out if things are properly set up (on a Jessie version from scratch)

```
> demsg
[    3.170995] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.278800] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0001
[    3.278839] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.278859] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB TouchController
[    3.278879] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: eGalax Inc.
[   10.294066] input: eGalax Inc. USB TouchController as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input2
[   10.311955] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbtouchscreen

> lsmod | grep touch
usbtouchscreen         14176  0

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0100
N: Name="eGalax Inc. USB TouchController"
P: Phys=usb-20980000.usb-1.3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event2
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
```

So I had pretty much the same outputs as the blogger described.

The questions you might help me with:

1. Am I guessing right that I don't need to compile a kernel? according to: [GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/718)
2. Should my display work with the setup from above?
3. How can I figure out, if my touch (device) works at all?

Answer (score 1):

You already got an input device, that's good as it means the kernel has an input driver for that touch controller. Now go and install the *evtest* tool to find out whether your device delivers events.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest

If that works, check whether your Touch is found by X11 by using

$ xinput list

Come again when you checked all these.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, meanwhile I'm on other projects, but I'll try next time I'm on the pi and let you know!